New to "box::" package. How to integrate magrittr pipe operator into module?
I've recently been exposed to the package "box" and thought it was just lovely to consolidate my functions into a single r-script from which I can import them into other scripts using
box::use(folder/myFunctionScript\[functionName\] #where myFunctionScript is actually an R-script (myFunctionScript.R)

I created the R-script containing functions that I can export.  Simple functions work fine using base functions or even calls to specific functions within other packages (like stats::qt()) work fine, but when I want to use magrittr's pipe operator (%>%) it breaks, and I cannot find any way to make it work.  I really want to preserve the ability to use the pipe operator, but I just can't figure it out.
I've seen some solutions that work inside packages but that don't seem to work in the roxygen2 & box modules.  That said, this is the first time I've tried to build anything like this.  So, maybe I'm just applying the solutions incorrectly.
I've tried all manner of things, including:
usethis::use_import_from("magrittr","%>%")
#' @importFrom
#' @import magrittr # doesn't matter, still doesn't recognize %>%
devtools::document() #apparently needs to be inside of a package or project
box::use(magrittr) # doesn't matter, still doesn't recognize %>% 

R's base pipe operator '|>' still doesn't work right, because it can't be nested
Here's the actual code I'm working on.  Not sure how to simplify, because the base pipe, for example causes an issue with the
caret::knnreg()
function which asks for a y argument that it doesn't typically ask for when the function is just run from the script I took it from.
    #' @export
    
    fun_KnnByK <- function(data = ISLR2::Boston, k.in = 30, LineColor = "blue",
    
    predx.fun = data.frame(lstat = seq(2, 37, len=201))){
    
    box::use(magrittr)
    # This is training on the full dataset:
    knn_fit.fun <- data %>% #using the Boston dataset 
      caret::knnreg(formula = medv ~ lstat, #response variable medv.  Predictor variable is lstat
             data = ., #Boston
             k = k.in) # using the 30 nearest neighbors
    
    return(knn_fit.fun)
    
    } #end fun_KnnByK

I was expecting the function to run like it normally does when I just use it in my original script

Have you seen https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/282? Try box::use(magrittr[%>%])

R's base pipe operator '|>' still doesn't work right, because it can't be nested--this conclusion is suspect.

This worked for me
box::use(./knn)
knn$fun_KnnByK()
## 30-nearest neighbor regression model

where knn.R is in current directory and contains:
#' @export

fun_KnnByK <- function(data = ISLR2::Boston, k.in = 30, LineColor = "blue",

predx.fun = data.frame(lstat = seq(2, 37, len=201))){

box::use(stats[...])

# box::use(magrittr)
# This is training on the full dataset:
knn_fit.fun <- data |> #using the Boston dataset 
  caret::knnreg(formula = medv ~ lstat, #response variable medv.  Predictor variable is lstat
         data = _, #Boston
         k = k.in) # using the 30 nearest neighbors

return(knn_fit.fun)

} #end fun_KnnByK

